# SQLite Select DISTINCT Values of a Column without Ordering

Tags: sqlite

I would like to know whether its possible to get a list of distinct values in a SQLite Column without ordering them.

I tried following query. But it automatically orders the unique text into ascending order.

> SELECT DISTINCT column FROM table;

Ex.

**Column**

```
Mathew
Mathew
John
John
John
Numbers
Numbers
```

---

**Result**

```
John
Mathew
Numbers
```

But I would like it not to be ordered. Would like it in Mathew, John, Numbers

Thanks.

Comment: In what order would you like the results? use `ORDER BY some_other_column`

Comment: I want it to be shown in appearing order without any ordering on the column texts. I have duplicate values close together.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

What order do you want?

If you want to get the values in the order of first appearance you can do:

```
select distinct column
  from table
 order by min(rowid);
```

Comment: I would like to have the same order that is in my table. But I don't understand above query. Could you explain it a little. I have duplicate values close together.

Comment: I have added INTEGER PRIMARY KEY Column with SQLiteBrowser and ORDERED BY that new Column MIN(). :) Thanks.

Comment: The rowid is an implicit INTEGER PRIMARY KEY. See http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html

Comment: Oh. So this could have easily worked. I can remove that column. it works :)

Comment: Here's a caveat for `count()`: you use `select count(distinct column)`, not `select distinct count(column)`.

Comment: [SQLite Lanuage](https://sqlite.org/lang.html) and [SELECT](https://sqlite.org/lang_select.html) helped me round out my query.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean "without ordering"?  There's no natural order implied in a SQL table, so the default ascending order by column from left to right is as good as any other order.  If you prefer another order, SELECT DISTINCT does accept an ORDER BY clause.

Comment: Actually with this query on SQLite, text of the column are ordered in Ascending Order.

Comment: Yes, that's my point.  The underlying table (form which the data was drawn) has no "natural" order, so how would you expect the result set to be sorted?  Ascending order makes as much sense as anything else, since there's no "unordered" order to be respected.

Comment: But when I tried the query it shows ordered with SQLite. I have edited my Question with results.

Answer (score 0):

hey one easy method will be adding a serial number(Make it primary Key) as you insert a record and make the order descending .