# How to check Duplicate items in sqlite phonegap

Tags: sqlite, cordova

I am creating a table in sqlite .Then i insert data in table.Take example I have table **A**
Having column ID Name.I  don't need any duplicate name .If i have already same name .I don't want to insert that name in my table .Mean i don't need duplicate items? How to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can the specify the ID as "PRIMARY KEY" and Name as "UNIQUE". Setting ID as primary key [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517579/strings-as-primary-keys-in-sql-database) helps. If the data base is already there and you want to you only distinct values you follow this[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4790162/sqlite-select-disticnt-values-of-a-column-without-ordering)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the column to be a "key" or declare the column to be "unique"

Here is an example:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
num    FLOAT NOT NULL,
cost   FLOAT NOT NULL,
paid   FLOAT NOT NULL,
date   DATE  NOT NULL,
UNIQUE(num));
```

Comment: I am using Sqlite using phonegap..i thing there is no such functionality